# How to lookup HBase REST API (Stargate) if the row-keys are reversed urls

Tags: rest, hadoop, hbase, nutch, stargate

I am using nutch2.2.1 + hbase0.90.4, and wanting to access the data via the [HBase REST API Stargate](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate). If I seed nutch with a url (eg. www.usatoday.com), the reversed url becomes the HBase row-key in the designated table ('webpage'). I can lookup the data via the hbase shell as follows:

```
hbase(main):001:0> get 'webpage', 'com.usatoday.www:http/'
COLUMN                                         CELL                                                                                                                                 
 f:fi                                          timestamp=1404762373394,value=\x00'\x8D\x00                                                                                         
 f:ts                                          timestamp=1404762373394, value=\x00\x00\x01G\x12\\xB5\xB3                                                                            
 mk:_injmrk_                                   timestamp=1404762373394, value=y                                                                                                     
 mk:dist                                       timestamp=1404762373394, value=0                                                                                                     
 mtdt:_csh_                                    timestamp=1404762373394, value=?\x80\x00\x00                                                                                         
 s:s                                           timestamp=1404762373394, value=?\x80\x00\x00
```

However, I am having trouble using the REST API. Presumably I need to do some pretty simple URL encoding to suppress the colon before 'http' that is making trouble for me?

For eg., I get a HTTP 404 when I try

```
curl http://localhost:8900/webpage/com.usatoday.www:http/
```

also when I try

```
curl http://localhost:8900/webpage/com.usatoday.www%3Ahttp/
```

I know that the REST API is working fine as I can create a row called 'row3' into a table called 'test' and lookup

```
curl http://localhost:8900/test/row3
```

to see the following expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><CellSet><Row key="cm93Mw=="><Cell timestamp="1404761922130" column="Y2Y6Yw==">dGhpcyBpcyBzb3J0YSB3b3JraW5nIG5vdw==</Cell></Row></CellSet>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to URL encode the forward slash as well. The following works.

```
curl http://localhost:8900/webpage/com.usatoday.www%3Ahttp%2F
```

Comment: what if the / is not the last character, but in the middle of something? I can't work it out having a key like this: '123/456/7'. Tried with "123%2F456%2F7", but doesn't work. any help would be great