# HBase REST java example

Tags: rest, hadoop, hbase, stargate

I am in a need to use HBase REST service to query a table. But all of the resources uses curl utility to do the hit. Is there any example that I can use to do it using the url?

### HBAse details

HBase REST URL: http://hbase-rest-server:8881/
Table: employee
Row key: 458k34
Columns: name, dept
Column family: cf

Can somebody show me the url to fetch the above row (this url will be accessed from a mobile app)?

Thanks in advance.
Arun

Comment: You may take a look at [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734045/how-to-lookup-hbase-rest-api-stargate-if-the-row-keys-are-reversed-urls